# Multiple beveled edges on the side on a object or bevel like patterns

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, bevel

I am trying to model this bottle shape but I don't know how to go about this. I was thinking first using a subdivision surface on a basic rounded rectangular shape, but as I am thinking of using booleans for create gap or hole to shape that I noticed this would create a lot of weird shading with this modifyer. Any idea how to make this?[image]

Comment: If you want my _opinion_, I would not use the boolean to make the "hole" Instead, enable a built in addon called "loop tools". Once enabled, select a square(ish) section of faces on the side of your object, then right click and select _loop tools > circle_.  From there, you can inset/extrude/delete - whatever you need to do. This will leave clean enough topology that you can still use the subdivision surface modifier on the object without shading issues.

Comment: do you have another picture of your bottle? It's hard to understand its shape... maybe juste extrude some edge loops?

Comment: Here is the image of the whole bottle https://ibb.co/YQFv3Y3